# What is "White space" in database sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, whitespace

Database increased in size drastically after a release in production environment. After getting a chart for the database, there is a "white space" in the chart generated by solarwinds, which started after the release.

What is white space? Any idea why this happened?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you use for exampe **NCHAR(200) o CHAR(200)**

but inside this column, you write just "**hello**" ( LEN("hello") is 5 ),
sql insert in the other **195 char** a space -> **whitespace**